# Filter Conditon in Rest API query Not Working

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, office-365, rest

Here `ESI_ProjectSeqNoLookup/Id` is a Lookup Column so expand used and filter `ESI_AFENo` type is `Hyperlink or Picture`. This query is not working.

```
query.RestQuery = "getbytitle('RFA')/Items?$select=ID,ESI_ProjectSeqNoLookup/Id&$expand=ESI_ProjectSeqNoLookup&$filter=ESI_AFENo eq 'A150434'";
```

Answer (score 1):

i believe you can't filter hyperlink column via rest. What you can do is use caml query with Rest api, that will solve your issue.

Here are the important things about it:

1. A REST request with a CAML query is always a POST request
2. A REST request with a CAML query has always to have X-RequestDigest
   http header (actually because it is a POST request)
3. A REST request with a CAML query should always have the attached
   CAML query in the request body (and not in a query string).
4. A REST request with a CAML query must have the http header
   “Content-Type: application/json;odata=verbose” unless you use xml in
   the request body

I have taken above reference from [this](http://tech.bool.se/using-caml-sharepoint-rest-api/) blog.

.

Answer (score 0):

It's a Limitation in SharePoint 2013 REST filter, You have to use CAML with REST -

```
url: "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListName')/getitems"
method: "POST",
body: "{ 'query' : {'__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.CamlQuery' }, "ViewXml": "<View><Query><Where><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='URL'/><Value Type='URL'>url</Value></BeginsWith></Where></Query></View>" } }",
headers: 
{
    "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
    "content-type": "application/json; odata=verbose"
}
```

Comment: In ViewXML we have to give Caml Query or URL??Caml Query:"<View><Query><Where><FieldRef Name='ESI_AFENo'/><Value Type='URL'>'A150434'</Value></Where></Query></View>"; like this????